# Cannot read property in ajax wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

i'm trying for get more article in php wordpress.
i using ajax and a php file for take 3 articles, but when i click button for load more post , i recived an error in console from jQuery.
This used to work , but now i can't run it.

this is Error :

```
jquery-3.4.0.min.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined
at k.fn.init.val (jquery-3.4.0.min.js:1)
at scripts.js?ver=5.5.1:1
at i (jquery-3.4.0.min.js:1)
at qt (jquery-3.4.0.min.js:1)
at qt (jquery-3.4.0.min.js:1)
at Object.<anonymous> (jquery-3.4.0.min.js:1)
at Function.each (jquery-3.4.0.min.js:1)
at qt (jquery-3.4.0.min.js:1)
at qt (jquery-3.4.0.min.js:1)
at qt (jquery-3.4.0.min.js:1)
```

and this is my script code :

```
$('#fetchArticle').click(function (html){
var offset = 0;
let current_page = document.querySelector(".posts_list").dataset.page;
let max_page = document.querySelector(".posts_list").dataset.max;
offset = offset + 3;
$(this).text('صبر کنید ...');
$(this).prop('disabled', true);
$btnLoad = $(this);
$val = $btnLoad.val();
$.ajax({
    url: 'moreArticle.php',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'html',
    data : 'html',
    cache: false,
    success : function (response){
        $('#Articles').append(response);
        $btnLoad.prop('disabled', false);
        $btnLoad.text('بارگذاری بیشتر ؟ ');
    },
    error: function ($e){
        alert('server connection is feild....!');
        $btnLoad.prop('disabled', false);
        $btnLoad.text('تلاش مجدد !');
        console.log($e);
    }

})
```

})

and my php code is :

```
<?php
 session_start();
require( 'wp-load.php' );
$args = array(
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => 3,
);

$my_post = new WP_Query( $args );
$html = '';
while ($my_post->have_posts()) {
    $my_post->the_post();
    $pic = get_the_post_thumbnail_url();
    $title = get_the_title();
    $categories = get_the_category();
    $cat = $categories[0]->name;
    function excerpt2($num) {
        $limit = $num+1;
        $excerpt = explode(' ', get_the_excerpt(), $limit);
        array_pop($excerpt);
        $excerpt = implode(" ",$excerpt). " ...";
        return $excerpt;
    }    
    $ex = excerpt2(10);
    $author = get_the_author();
    $time = get_the_time();
    $link = get_the_permalink();
    $html .= '<div class="col-md-4"><div class="card card-blog"><div class="card-image"><a     
    href="#pablo"><img class="img" alt="'.get_the_title().'" src="'.$pic.'" /></a></div>';
    $html .= '<div class="card-content"><h6 class="category text-danger"><i class="material-icons">                
    </i>'.$cat.'</h6><h4 class="card-title"><a href="#pablo">'.$title.'</a></h4>';
    $html .= '<div class="footer text-center"><div class="author"><a href="#pablo"> 
    <span>'.$author.'</span><img src="" alt="..." class="avatar img-raised"></a></div>';
    $html .= '<div class="stats"><i class="material-icons">schedule</i>'.$time.'</div>';
    $html .= '<a href="'.$link.'" class="btn btn-primary btn-round"><i class="material-    
    icons">format_align_right</i> ادامه مطلب</a></div></div></div>';
    echo $html;
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

Where is my problem?
I'm confused!

Comment: You are trying to `toLowerCase` something that is not a string, maybe you just fetched a null from the remote.

Comment: thank you , it's worked.